# Program hanging at call for REST service

Tags: java, jsp, rest, tomcat

I am running a `REST` service on `Tomcat` and a client service from `Eclipse`.

My program keeps stopping when on it's second run through. I am not receiving any exceptions in the console running `Tomcat`

The first time my `Controller` is called, there is no issue and everything runs fine. After everything executes in the `Controller`, the user is redirected back to a `JSP` page. When a button is clicked on the `JSP` page, the `Controller` code shown below is run again.

However this time, the program stops in the function:

```
getOrderDetails(id, order, service);
```

while executing the line:

```
String orderXML = service.path("rest").path("coffee").header("user", "customer-123").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(String.class);
```

This line calls the `REST` service which will interact with my SQLite database and then return some `XML.

I really cannot work out why it is stopping on the second attempt!

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thank you!

`Update 1:` If it's of any significance, I find that when the program hangs, I need to not only quit `Eclipse` and restart it, but I also need to restart the server. Otherwise, the client program won't work properly.

`Update 2:` I have defined only one ClientResponse to be used at all points in the program.

`Update 3:` I've been using `ClientResponse.close()` after each of my requests.

`NOTE: Code updated to reflect comment below`

`Controller:`

```
 static ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
 static Client client = Client.create(config);
 static WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
ClientResponse clientResp;

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
    processRequest(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
    processRequest(request, response);
}

private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {        

    // Get All Coffee Orders
    clientResp = service.path("rest").path("coffee").header("user", "customer-123").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class);

    String orderXML = clientResp.getEntity(String.class);

    clientResp.close();         

    try {
        Document document = loadXMLFromString(orderXML);
        NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                      
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {                       
                Element elem = (Element) node;

                CoffeeOrder order = new CoffeeOrder();

                // Set ID
                String id = elem.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                order.setId(id);

                // Get ALL Order Details
                getOrderDetails(id, order);

                // Get ALL Payment Details
                getPaymentDetails(id, order);                                                   


                // If order has not been cancelled, add to open orders
                if (!order.getOrderStatus().equals("cancelled")){
                    openOrders.add(order);
                    // If order has been cancelled, add to cancelled orders.
                } else {
                    cancelledOrders.add(order);
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
}


    // Get all Order Details
private void getOrderDetails(String id, CoffeeOrder order){

    // PROGRAM STOPS HERE ON SECOND RUN THROUGH 

    clientResp = service.path("rest").path("coffee").path(id).header("user", "customer-123").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class);

    orderXML = clientResp.getEntity(String.class);

    clientResp.close();

    // Do Things here with XML

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// Get all Payment Details
private void getPaymentDetails(String id, CoffeeOrder order){

    clientResp = service.path("rest").path("payment").path(id).header("user", "customer-123").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class);

    orderXML = clientResp.getEntity(String.class);

    clientResp.close();

    // Do Things here with XML


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than reusing the service object, did you try creating a new service object for each call? Just make your client object static and call client.resource before any web service call.

Comment: @kharyam I made the changes you suggested but I am still having the same issue. I have updated my code above. Is this what you meant? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Close - instead of making service static just create it before each call (don't reuse it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised what the problem was...

It had to do with multiple database connections that were being opened on the server side! This was causing the issue and once I dealt with that the problem resolved itself.

Thanks for all your help!